# Implementing a Windows 8 app with nested navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm currently developing an app for Windows 8 which should provide nested navigation. The main view is split into 3 parts, a menu area on the left side, a Content area and a Header. Both the menu and the Header should be visible all the time. [image]

The Content area is filled with the Content selected from the main menu, however if the user selects for example a list, the Content area is again split into two sections where i want to Show the list on the left side and the selected Detail Information on the right side (similar to the built-in mail app). The Detail view again has subviews, which should be displayed in the same area. I added a back button to navigate through the Detail views. [image]

Each of the views is currently contained in a Frame element, which means i have a MenuFrame and ContentFrame inside the main view, and a ListFrame and a DetailFrame inside the "list"-view. I maintain backstacks for every Frame to enable navigating back.

My question is: if the user wants to snap the application (Display it side by side with other Win8-Apps or the Desktop), the space for the app is very small. Therefore i want to Display only one view at a time in snapped mode, which means the user first sees the main menu, then the list, then the Detail view, and he should be able to navigate back to the parent view in all cases (which means that i would have to maintain a single backstack for all views?).

Is there a simple way to achieve this behavior?

Another question: Currently i don't use the Frame.Navigate-methods, but i implemented my own backstack by just creating UserControls and assigning them to the Frame.Content property. If the app wants to navigate back, the previous control is popped from the stack and set as the Frame Content. The benefit of this is that i can execute code in the control constructor which might raise exceptions. Are there any downside of this method or other reasons why you would recommend switching to the standard Frame.Navigate() pattern?

Comment: `execute code in the control constructor which might raise exceptions` - Don't put code in Controls constructors. Actually don't put any (unneeded) codebehind at all. Learn MVVM.

Comment: Actually i'm using MVVM, but the ViewModel is inside a core-assembly that also has to run on MonoDroid and Windows Phone, so some code is still required for platform-specific customizations. Thank you for your comment anyway, i will investigate if i can move more code from the control constructors to the viewmodel.

Comment: So, I don't have time at the moment to write out a full example, but if you go into many of the app samples, they basically do this by creating `Page` classes, then setting them as children of `ContentControl`s, like `StackPanel`s or `Grid`s. You can do this recursively as well (so, create a new Page that has the Combination of the `ListView` and a blank `Content` ares, then set it in the same fashion).

Comment: Hi, I know that I'm quite late, but I was facing a similar problem and for the moment I solved it with a flipview binded to an observable collection, with a nested observable collection binded to a listview ... now I was looking if there was some better solution, but till now couldn't find it. cheers :)